# Marine engines?

Tags: discussion

**Part 1:** I know that per FAQ, an idea of this site, we are constrained with on-road vehicles. But what about questions about automotive engines in marine applications? Many recreational boats use automobile engines. Companies like German Tognum/MTU (owners of Detroit Diesel) also use same engines from trucks, to construction equipment, to power generation, to rail transport, and yes, as marine propulsion. Can the questions about such motors be allowed so long they do not concern marine-specific topics (say, use of outboard water for cooling)?

**Part 2:** [SE Recreational Boating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38237/recreational-boating) is in its infancy, and there is no beginning in sight (5 followers to proposal so far). Is there any better place outside of MVM&R to ask question about non-automotive marine engines (I need help identifying 70s Mariner outboard, for instance)?

**Note:** in both cases, boats are motor vehicles. They just use water to support themselves instead of asphalt.

Answer (score 3):

[The FAQ states](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and
>   their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications
>   other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or
>   engine accessories

**internal combustion engines, even in applications other than automotive**

Based on that those question would be welcome here.

Comment: I have to concur: it's not like the technologies are so very different.